# How to change R plot default options

Tags: r, defaults

I'd like to change default plot option from `type = "p"` to `type = "l"` ; I mean I want it is like that at the beginning of each new session, without specifying it any more.

I've tried to put some piece of code in my `Rprofile.site` but unfortunately not the right one: firstly I wanted to use `setDefaults` but this package is deprecated; I also tried to set a hook but couldn't make it work.

Any ideas ?

thanks !

Comment: That could have undesired consequences for functions using `plot` internally. You should define a `lplot` function instead.

Comment: Do you mean you didn't put the right code in your Rprofile, or you didn't put code in the right Rprofile?

Comment: @Roland : that makes sense, even though I do it manually with `fix(plot.default)` and never had any issue so far

Comment: @Benjamin : yes I know how to edit the `Rprofile.site` file, but I didn't find what to write in it to get my result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *could* be done by adding to your Rprofile

```
formals(plot.default)$type <- "l"
```

But that would be highly discouraged, for the reasons Roland states in his comment.  A better solution would be to place this in your Rprofile:

```
lplot <- function(x, y, type = "l", ...){
    plot(x, y, type = type, ...)
}
```

This gives you the default you want, the ability to revert back to normal if wanted, and doesn't affect the existing `plot` function.

But this still comes with the downside of the `lplot` function seemingly appearing out of nowhere.  Far better would be to put `lplot` in a package.  Even if you load the package in the Rprofile, at least `?lplot` will pull up something to indicate where it came from.

Comment: `formals` was exactly the function I was looking for. I understand the drawbacks for `plot` but this was also just a MWE for SO, I'd like to do it with some other functions. Thanks !

Comment: I got the error `Error “cannot do complex assignments in base namespace”`, do you know how to handle that ?